# Checkboxes not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my check boxes are not getting checked, when created dynamically. I am not able to find the problem. Though, when I hard-code the values for `check box id` and `label for`, it just works.

```
var category_list = this.props.categories_list.map(function(name, i) {
        // debugger
        return (
            <div className="group-chkbx list-group-item">
                <input key={i+11} type="checkbox" id={name.category_id} name="category" />
                <label htmlFor={name.category_id}>{name.name}</label>
            </div>
        )
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean, that when you click on the checkbox it doesn't show the check mark? or that you are not able to get the value (checked/unchecked)?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't put the check mark on the check box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research one of my colleague helped me out with a solution. The `htmlFor` and `id` must be same, `but cannot be only numeric`. The Ids that I'm using are purely numeric. When I added alphabet as a prefix, it just started working like charm. Thanks all for showing interest and helping out here.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that would set the `checked` prop on them, anyway. When should they be checked?

(Also, remember that components in arrays (such as what `.map` returns) [should have unique `key` props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html).)

Comment: I have added unique keys to check boxes too, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your checkboxes are not getting **checked**, most probably is that some other functionality is preventing it. 
Here and example of how to get the checkbox values:

```
class WithChecks extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);
    }
    getValue(e){
        const chk = e.target;
        console.log(chk.checked);
        console.log(chk.value);
    }

    render() {
        const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    arr.map((value, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <input type="checkbox" 
                                       id={'chk' + index} 
                                       onChange={this.getValue}
                                       name="category" 
                                       value={value} />
                                <label htmlFor={'chk' + index}>{value}</label>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Maybe this can help to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The checked property of the input will control whether it is checked. Usually I use local state (or something from global redux state to control what is checked). Little Example:

```
class Something extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: 0
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        // Do Stuff
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.props.categories_list.map(function(name, i) {
                        return (
                            <div className="group-chkbx list-group-item" key={i}>
                                <input checked={i === this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleChange} type="checkbox" id={name.category_id} name="category" />
                                <label htmlFor={name.category_id}>{name.name}</label>
                            </div>
                        )
                    });
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```